# getting an error in entity-framework using many to many relationship

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework

I have two tables called Buttons and Tiles with many-to-many relationship as follows:

```
Buttons            *-----------
    ButtonID                  |
    Title                     |
                              |
Tiles              *-----------
    TileID
    Title
```

Now I am trying to query it something like :

```
b = new ObservableCollection<Buttons>(from x in db.Buttons
                                      where x.Tile == SelectedTileObj
                                      select x);
```

But I am getting an error as mentioned below:

```
Unable to create a constant value of type 'Data.Tiles'.
Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
```

Comment: u cannot compare complex types in EQuery bcoz it cannot be transformed into a sql query!...u can only perform comparison on basic types(int,float,string...etc)...Consider Comparing TileId instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `TileID` is a primary key, you could take another approach:

- select the tiles that interest you (have the right id)
- using the navigation property, get the buttons associated with the above tiles

  `var tiles = db.Tiles.Where(t => t.TileId == SelectedTileObj.TileId);`
  `// t.Buttons should be the navigation property for retrieving associated buttons`
  `var buttons = tiles.SelectMany(t => t.Buttons);`
  `var b = new ObservableCollection<Buttons>(b);`